# VLC desktop capture screen-width option not working as expected

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-capture

I'm attempting to capture my desktop using VLC. When I run `vlc screen:// --screen-fps=15 --screen-width=500` it behaves as if I had run `vlc screen:// --screen-fps=15 --screen-width=1000` or `vlc screen:// --screen-fps=15`, which is capturing the entire primary monitor size and nothing else. I can move the top left corner around using `--screen-top` and `--screen-left`, even to where the capture window is entirely blank. Nothing I do short of changing the resolution of my desktop can change the overall size of the capture window.

How do I adjust the capture width? My end goal is to capture 2 monitors simultaneously but I think if I can resolve the width issue that will be taken care of (I can already see the second monitor by moving around the capture window).

Update regarding 2 monitors: VLC 2.x was still unhappy with capturing more than one screen's woth of pixels despite being able to set the capture to a smaller window, so I tried 3.02 which appears to capture all monitors by default which is what I wanted to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the height as well, e.g.:

```
vlc screen:// --screen-fps=15 --screen-width=500 --screen-height=500
```